# Filter filenames by pattern

Tags: perl, grep, readdir

I need to search for files in a directory that begin with a particular pattern, say "abc". I also need to eliminate all the files in the result that end with ".xh". I am not sure how to go about doing it in Perl.

I have something like this:

```
opendir(MYDIR, $newpath);
my @files = grep(/abc\*.*/,readdir(MYDIR)); # DOES NOT WORK
```

I also need to eliminate all files from result that end with ".xh"

Thanks, Bi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
@files = grep {!/\.xh$/} <$MYDIR/abc*>;
```

where MYDIR is a string containing the path of your directory.

Answer (score 7):

> opendir(MYDIR, $newpath); my @files = grep(/abc*.*/,readdir(MYDIR)); #DOES NOT WORK

You are confusing a regex pattern with a glob pattern.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

opendir my $dir_h, '.'
    or die "Cannot open directory: $!";

my @files = grep { /abc/ and not /\.xh$/ } readdir $dir_h;

closedir $dir_h;

print "$_\n" for @files;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
opendir(MYDIR, $newpath) or die "$!";
my @files = grep{ !/\.xh$/ && /abc/ } readdir(MYDIR);
close MYDIR;
foreach (@files) { 
   do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The point that kevinadc and Sinan Unur are using but not mentioning is that `readdir()` returns a list of all the entries in the directory when called in list context.  You can then use any list operator on that.  That's why you can use:

```
my @files = grep (/abc/ && !/\.xh$/), readdir MYDIR;
```

So:

```
readdir MYDIR
```

returns a list of all the files in MYDIR.

And:

```
grep (/abc/ && !/\.xh$/)
```

returns all the elements returned by `readdir MYDIR` that match the criteria there.

Comment: Modify that second check to be /\.xh$/ and you'll be checking the right thing. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach $file (@files)
{
    my $fileN = $1 if $file =~ /([^\/]+)$/;

    if ($fileN =~ /\.xh$/)
    {
          unlink $file;
          next;
    }
    if ($fileN =~ /^abc/)
    {
          open(FILE, "<$file");
          while(<FILE>)
          {
             # read through file.
          }
    }
 }
```

also, all files in a directory can be accessed by doing:

```
$DIR = "/somedir/somepath";
foreach $file (<$DIR/*>)
{
  # apply file checks here like above.
}
```

ALternatively you can use the perl module File::find.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `opendir` and filtering `readdir` (don't forget to `closedir`!), you could instead use `glob`:

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile splitpath);

my @files =
    grep !/^\.xh$/,                # filter out names ending in ".xh"
    map +(splitpath $_)[-1],       # filename only
    glob                           # perform shell-like glob expansion
        catfile $newpath, 'abc*';  # "$newpath/abc*" (or \ or :, depending on OS)
```

If you don't care about eliminating the `$newpath` prefixed to the results of [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), get rid of the `map+`[`splitpath`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec/Functions.html).

Comment: There's no need for the map or the splitpath. Either it ends in .xh or it doesn't. The extra work doesn't change that.

Comment: Huh?  glob("./abc*") returns ("./abc.txt", "./abc.xh"); how else do you expect to twiddle that down to ("abc.txt")?